# Story ID: Guy with daily anterograde amnesia. Female doctor becomes expert on it. Attempt to cure him fails

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about a guy with [anterograde amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterograde_amnesia) (i.e. being unable to form new memories, as in the film "Memento" or a case described in one of the chapters in the 1985 book *[The Man Who Mistook His Wife for a Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Mistook_His_Wife_for_a_Hat)* by Dr. Oliver Sacks). I don't recall how he got the condition, but I think, in contrast to real-life anterograde amnesia, the guy in this story experienced each day from beginning to end. I think there was a neuroscience researcher, I believe female, who devotes herself to working on a cure for it. At the end, some cure procedure is attempted, but it doesn't work right -- it feels like a thousands of himself (one from each day) are being shoved together. There's some mention by the researcher, toward the end, of how studying him has given science revolutionary insight into the human brain.

This would have been published before "Memento" (2000). Possibly decades before.

I was reminded of this story by [a story ID](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172868/a-short-story-about-a-frozen-state-man) that was resolved as being "Invariant" (1944) by John R. Pierce, but it isn't that one.

Comment: What about this story makes it scifi or fantasy, rather than just clinical research?

Comment: Sounds like science-fiction to me, providing revolutionary insight into the brain? Although I'm not sure how we necessarily classify this sort of thing.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Not sure if that qualifies, but I'm not sure how groundbreaking medical research would be classified. If the OP could clarify *how* the cure is attempted, that might help.

Comment: @JohnP, under the presumption that it’s fictitious science, it sounds like hard-sci-fi to me

Comment: @Edlothiad - That is a good point. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: @JohnP Late response, since you already retracted the close vote, but to answer your question: It was some sort of fictitious procedure, but I don't remember the details of the procedure. Like other stories involving fictitious types of treatment of neurological disorders (Greg Egan's "Reasons to Be Cheerful", a 1998 Locus for Best Novelette nominee, and "Flowers for Algernon" spring to mind) it would indeed qualify as SF. (And I almost surely read it in either an SF magazine or an SF collection, like a "Year's Best" or some well-known SF author's anthology.)

Comment: @Edlothiad "Although I'm not sure how we necessarily classify this sort of thing." As medical science fiction? Like I said above, it sits alongside other SF stories that describe fictitious neurological treatments, like "Flowers for Algernon" and "Reasons to be Cheerful". There's also apparently a term "neuroscience fiction" that's been suggested, although apparently it often refers to more than just stories of therapeutic intervention. (See, for example, https://dynamicsubspace.net/research/neuroscience-and-science-fiction-literature/ )

Comment: @JacobC. that was my reasoning for leaving it open. I just wasn't certain if we (the site) had a policy on such thing.